# What is wrong in select str_to_date ( '%e %b %Y','14 Aug 1987' )

Tags: mysql

What is wrong in

```
select str_to_date ( '%e %b %Y','14 Aug 1987' )
```

I even tried '%d %b %Y'

Referred http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because it is "STRING" to "DATE" ... put the string first ...

```
select str_to_date ( '14 Aug 1987','%e %b %Y' )
```

Comment: Oops !! Sorry.. My mistake.